# Pacman cannot install arch linux keyring on arch linux arm

Tags: pacman, arch-arm

After a fresh installation of Arch Linux Arm (10 hours ago as of the time of writing) on the raspberry pi 3 model b+ using the Armv7h architecture, I cannot install the Arch Linux Keyring, which inturn prevents the installation of other pieces of software. Pacman states "File /var/cache//pacman/pkg/archlinux-keyring-20180404-1-any.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))."

I have been very comfortably using Arch Linux ARM for 6 months now, and I had to reinstall it after updating four days ago (as of the time of writing) after pacman began telling me the same issue. I have already ran pacman-key - - init on this installation. The installation also has no other software installed.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28invalid_or_corrupted_package.29.22_error

Answer (score 4):

```
pacman-key -u
pacman-key --populate
```

…should help.